# return outside function, I don't believe it's indentation (return must be inside a function! can not test with statements)

Tags: python-3.x, return, syntax-error

## Update (return must be inside a function! can not test with statements)

Keep getting

File "python", line 49
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

```
bank=100
while True:
  print('How much would you like to bet?')
  bet=input()
  bet=int(bet)
  if bet not in range(1,bank+1):
    print('please enter an amount you have!')
  else:
    return bet
```

Not exactly sure what is going on wrong and sorry for poor formatting but doing my best.

Update:

[A run of it using repl.it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7omtg.jpg)

and the code itself

https://repl.it/Hl0p/0

Comment: We don't have 49 lines in this code, so there must be some difference between the code you posted here and the code that's failing. Can you make a copy of the code you have and try to reduce it this small and give the error message from that?

Comment: Yeah I can but it's all just definitions, even as just this snip it in a separate page it won't work.

Comment: Just for the future, it's better to post the error message from your reduced code than from your full code. Also, you could have reduced this one further, and you probably would have found the solution on your own in doing so.

Comment: I might have figured it out on my own eventually but as silly as it sounds, this was the end of my hour long frustration of testing. I knew another code I was biasing mine off worked and mine didn't but I didn't understand why. I didn't realize I left the error message from the line 49 but I will definitely keep that in mind for future reference. Thank you for your input and for taking the time to look over my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a function to return values. Only a function can return values. Your code is a collection of statements and not a function. See how to write function over here.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: Jfc thank you so much, I will eventually be in a definition but I was trying to test it before putting it into the definition and I completely forgot about this! I got it up and working now. Thank you. 

I can't accept your answer yet but I will asap.